How to extract DCT coefficient matrix by jpeglib in python?
I have the below code and i get  this error:
File "C:\Users\omar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jpeglib\functional.py", line 71, in read_dct
return DCTJPEG(
^^^^^^^^
TypeError: DCTJPEG.init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'
mport jpeglib
im = jpeglib.read_dct("tree.jpg")
Luminance = im.Y
Chr = im.Cr
Chb = im.Cb
Quan = im.qt
print(Quan)

I need to get metadata of jpeg image by jpeglib library in python

You're going to have to read the documentation for your library. What you are doing makes no sense. For example, there can be multiple quantization tables in a JPEG stream.

typo:  mport should be import.
